# 256 color in Linux console

Tags: linux, colors, console, tty

I have in my .bashrc

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

but this cause blinking all colored text (ls --color, in vim etc.) in a Linux console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>).

So is there any possibility to recognize in which terminal I am (Linux console or a pseudo-tty) so I can export TERM variable with valid value?

[EDIT]

I found alternative solution only:

for vim user (in .vimrc)

```
set t_Co=256
```

or for xterm in .Xdefaults (after that xrdb -load .Xdefaults)

```
XTerm*termName:         xterm-256color
```

or for screen (.screenrc)

```
term screen-256color
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try not exporting the `TERM` variable at all. This should be set by the terminal itself to an appropriate value. The linux console should set this to `linux`, while various X based terminal programs might use the value you set.

You should only set this as an override for when the default values do not work or don't get passed as when SSH'ing to a location that does not recognize your environment.

Comment: I didn't know that. Still learning. I set 256 color directly from .vimrc.

Answer (score 5):

The console $TERM is `linux`,[1] so you can construct a test, like so:

```
if [ "$TERM" = "linux" ]; then
...
```

As [Caleb notes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16387/256-color-in-real-console/16389#16389), setting the environment variable TERM to the type of terminal you would like to emulate is not a good idea.

See http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Text-Terminal-HOWTO-10.html#term_not_for_emulation for details

> [1] Since kernel version 1.3.2, the kernel default for the console is TERM=linux.

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-11.html

Comment: +1 documentation link. Still not reading the documentation enough :D.