# Detect if running in a virtual terminal?

Tags: shell-script, terminal, console, tty

I'd like to [autologin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152026/how-can-i-automatically-login-on-a-tty-and-execute-a-script) to `tty1` on login and then use `vlock` to lock it.

How can I detect from Bash if the current terminal is a console virtual terminal (e.g. `tty1`), so that I can put the `vlock` line into `.bash_profile` and have it run only if logging in through `tty1`?

Comment: I think you should change the title to "Detect if running in a virtual terminal" because `tty` can be misunderstood to mean detect if the current shell is connected to a pseudo-terminal device.

Comment: @JosephR. Thanks for pointing that out, fixed

Comment: @JosephR: bad call. A pseudo-terminal device is **p** ty, not tty. About to revert to original title.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16387/256-color-in-linux-console

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `tty` to get the name of the current virtual terminal, then test against it with a `case` statement:

```
#!/bin/sh

case $(tty) in /dev/tty[0-9]*)
    vlock ;;
esac
```

Comment: Even better, instead of assuming all terminal login shells are ttys.

Comment: No need to exclude X: if the script is running in a terminal emulator under X, `tty` will show the terminal emulator's pseudoterminal, not the physical terminal that X is running on.

Answer (score 7):

It is generally sufficient to simply test STDIN (FD0):

```
[ -t 0 ] && echo "TTY available" || echo "No TTY available"
```

Comment: OK, because `.bash_profile` is called on login shells and the normal GUI login doesn't have a terminal, so the only terminal login shell should be a tty. Good find

Comment: If this snippet were included in a larger script that had its stdin redirected from a file, it would report that no TTY is available even if run from a VT.

Comment: @JosephR Correct. The value is often with `cron` or `at` jobs to avoid failures when scripts assume interactive input.